# Getting String Index Out of range -7 error

Tags: javascript, protractor

String Index Out of range error -7, when trying to click button.

Please find my code below,.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolderView_ctlRegistration_CustomerDetail_TextBox2")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolderView_ctlRegistration_CustomerDetail_TextBox3")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolderView_ctlRegistration_CustomerDetail_Button2")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ContentPlaceHolderView_ctlRegistration_CustomerDetail_Button2")).click();
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolderView_ctlRegistration_Panel1']/table/tbody/tr[16]/td/label")).getText().toString().trim().matches(this.getProperties("CSR_Success_Message"))==true);
break;
```

The page is common for all test methods.
Above code is working fine for one of the test methods. But is not working for other methods.

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal runnable example that demonstrates the problem when run](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This question contains not enough of the relevant code and too much irrelevant extra code.

Comment: Why would you ever `assertTrue(thing==true)`?

Comment: And had at least TWO people format your code

Comment: You should probably throw a protractor tag on this.

Answer (score 0):

**PLEASE PROVIDE ONCLICK FUNCTION FOR ContentPlaceHolderView_ctlRegistration_CustomerDetail_Button2**

I have confirmed the following line

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolderView_ctlRegistration_Panel1']/table/tbody/tr[16]/td/label"));
System.out.println(element.getText().toString().trim());
System.out.println(element.getText().toString().trim().matches("CSR_Success_Message"));
```

works for the following html

```
<div id="ContentPlaceHolderView_ctlRegistration_Panel1">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<label text="ok1">ok2</label>
</td>
</tr>
... 16 trs
```

using

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
```

outputs

```
ok2
false
```

i dont know what the cause of this error might be. IT seems it must be in the javascript of the button which has not been provided in the question